# Open a tooltip or a pop-up window using circular menu

Tags: menu, navigation, popup, window, tooltip

This is a simple HTML with CSS and JS. Circular menu with icons:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>test</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"href=
"https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

</head>

<body>

<nav class="circular-menu">

<div class="circle">
<a href="#" class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-skype fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></a>
</div>
<a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>

<script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It is working fine, but what I want is onclick pop-up window or onclick tooltip when users click icons. Onclick pop-up window or onclick tooltip must be responsive.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle please or somthing that works

Comment: I will give you a link to jsfiddle, hold on

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uh1bs8my/3/

Comment: Sorry @Ajonnes so you want a pop up when you click an icon? or just a tooltip when click?

Comment: As long as text content for that kind of box accepts html. I was thinking of a pop-up window at first glance (due to responsiveness)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? It's dirty but to have an idea

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.circle a');

for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++) {
  items[i].style.left = (50 - 35*Math.cos(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
  
  items[i].style.top = (50 + 35*Math.sin(-0.5 * Math.PI - 2*(1/l)*i*Math.PI)).toFixed(4) + "%";
}

document.querySelector('.menu-button').onclick = function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); document.querySelector('.circle').classList.toggle('open');
}

$('.demo').tooltip({
  trigger: 'click',
  placement: 'bottom'
});

function setTooltip(btn, message) {
  btn.tooltip('hide')
    .attr('data-original-title', message)
    .tooltip('show');
}

function hideTooltip(btn) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    btn.tooltip('hide');
  }, 1000);
}

// Clipboard

var clipboard = new Clipboard('.demo');

clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
 var btn = $(e.trigger);
  setTooltip(btn, 'Copied');
  hideTooltip(btn);
});
```

```css
@import "https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css";

body {
   background: url() no-repeat top center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: contain;
   -moz-background-size: contain;
   -o-background-size: contain;
   background-size: 338px 151px;
   background-position: top center;
   max-width:100%;
   height:auto;
   
}

.circular-menu {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
   
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);

  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
}

.open.circle {
  opacity: 1;
  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.circle a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 70px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  position: absolute;   
}

.circle a:hover {
  color: gray;
}

.menu-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 30px);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #dde;
}

.menu-button:hover {
  background-color: #eef;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body>

<nav class="circular-menu">

  <div class="circle">
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-home fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-linkedin fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-skype fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></a>
   <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-envelope fa-2x"></a>
    <a href="#" data-clipboard-text="1" class="demo fa fa-user fa-2x"></a>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="menu-button fa fa-bars fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
  
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You got me on the right track, thank you very much Cristian !! :) The magic was 
inside the <a href class>:)